# React icon installation error while running command line

Tags: reactjs

I have tried the 'npm install @react-icons/all-files --save'
but it gives error like '**npm ERR! code UNKNOWN**'

[Here is a screenshot of my command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2wiH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2wiH.png)

Answer (score 0):

your screenshot shows you are installing `npm install @heroicons/react` not `npm install react-icons`
follow this instructions as refrenced here:
https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/